# I can't set TimeZone to Calendar

Tags: java

I don't understand output of following code is 12- 12-1991,

Please explain for me, Thank for your help

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+7"));
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        c.set(1991, 11, 12);
        Date d = c.getTime();              
        System.out.println(simpleDF.format(d));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

months is zero index based. You need to have `10` instead of `11`.

Alternatively instread of using integers directly, you can write meaningfully.

```
 c.set(1991,Calendar.NOVEMBER, 12);
```

Where `Calendar.NOVEMBER` is a `static int` field which represents `NOVEMBER`.

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't enough ruputation to do upvote your answer. I am going to accept:(

Comment: Thats fine, I am glad that I could help :). I added a better `set` method that avoids confusion of integers in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

January is Month 0, so when you set 11 that is December
Check [java.util.Date docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 1):

Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.

You have to change

```
c.set(1991, 11, 12);
```

To

```
c.set(1991, 10, 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29):

**set**

```
public final void set(int year,
                  int month,
                  int date)
```

> Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH. Previous values of other calendar fields are retained. If this is not desired, call clear() first.
>   Parameters:
>   year - the value used to set the YEAR calendar field.
>   month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. **Month value is 0-based**. e.g., 0 for January.
>   date - the value used to set the DAY_OF_MONTH calendar field.